# Next Instance Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my blog app, I can call `@article.comments.last`. How do I create a `next_comment` method, one that *always* picks the next comment in line?

Update:
Also, how do I do the reverse, define a `previous_comment` method?

Update answer below.

Previous record:

```
  class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.previous(comment, key = :id)
      self.where("#{key} < ?", commend.send(key)).first
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to define a "next", you must declare a sorting rule. There is no "next" without an order.

The order can be as simple as by primary key, or another field (e.g. a name). The following method should support both cases, and default to "id"

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.next(comment, key = :id)
    self.where("#{key} > ?", comment.send(key)).first
  end
end
```

You should call it on the chain and pass the comment instance, so that it can use the same relation you used to load the original comment

```
scope = @article.comments
last = scope.last
next = scope.next(last)
```

Another (maybe simpler) solution is to simply load two objects

```
current, next = @article.comments.take(2)
```

You can also make it a method

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.first_and_next
    # use all to create a scope in case you call
    # the method directly on the Comment class
    all.take(2)
  end
end
    
current, next = @article.comments.first_and_next(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a pagination gem, like `will_paginate`, this will work

```
# Article model
def next_comment
  @page ||= 0
  @page += 1
  comments.page(@page).per(1).first
end
```

Or if you don't want to store the state

```
# Comment model
def next_comment
  article.comments.where("id > ?", id).first
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirty solution:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def next_comment
    article.comments.where('id > ?', id).first
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that this will load any comment, not just the comment related to the article in question.

Comment: sry,  i got this possibility a min ago, just for check:)

Comment: is this solution not database friendly?